# How to Custom Paint in the TextBox of an WUP - XAML - C# Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal

I have just started onto C# & Windows Universal Apps. I just can't seem to find a way to Override the `onPaint` or `onRender` of the `TextBox`.
Is it that XAML - WUP just supports styles or is there some problem in my syntax.

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace GotIt
{
    class CutomText : TextBox
    {

        protected override onRender ... Gives no suitable method found

        protected override onPaint...Gives no suitable method found
    }
}
```

Comment: i can be more specific about the problem if it's not in an understandable format ..

Comment: What do you want to do with `TextBlock`? To change the style of the text inside it from the code behind?

Comment: nope , i want to paint a line and a circle inside , you know paint graphics inside the textbox .. maybe image , maybe line or arc or fillrect etc..

Comment: You should use canvas to paint such objects in a container. TextBox is for text input.

Comment: yes but i would like to know if it is posibble ! And if yes , then how ?

Comment: I think you can use [Win2D](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm) package in your project, there are some samples in this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting the job done using Win2D . Great Package Indeed .

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnVdb.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxBdc.png)

Thanks Grace . 
Yaba Daba Doo .